# Add-on to auto-populate latitude/longitude fields based on user-entered location?

Tags: channel-entries, add-on, custom-fields

I'm using [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/) to create a map page displaying events with descriptive map pins based on location. The javascript initialization for each pin looks like the following:

```
L.marker([41.8781136, -87.62979819999998], {icon: mainIcon}).addTo(map)
```

I'm then binding a pop-up to each pin with text to describe the relevant event. Thus, I'm wondering if there is an EE add-on that would, ideally, auto-populate fields for latitude and longitude when a user enters a city and state-- such as San Francisco, CA-- from which I can then pull the info with EE channel fields via in the following manner:

```
L.marker([{lat}, {lon}], {icon: mainIcon}).addTo(map)
```

This is all the functionality I would need-- is there a simple add-on out there that would make this possible? Thanks for any guidance here.

Comment: If you use Channel Forms - why just don't do JS request for this and populate hidden lat/long fields?

Comment: Thanks Max- I'm relatively new to EE and not sure what you mean by Channel Forms, can you elaborate on your answer? I have a set of custom fields configured for an "Events" channel for which users data via the standard "publish" EE form.

Comment: so, they add this data inside CP?

Comment: Given that the number of cities to be chosen is finite, I ended up creating categories for each location with category fields for the latitude and longitude values for each city (I'm loving the categories feature in EE :)